# Convering Select Statement into Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using this query to pull a certain row (2) from 6 results but I want to run a update query on the title on row (2) from 6 results of data.

Do I have to use a UNION? I don't know how to write the query.

```
with cte as
(
    Select Title, Title_Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)
    From products.features
    where productid = '172'
)
select Title
from cte
where Title_Row = 2
```

thanks

Comment: Removed the `[mysql]` tag.

Comment: you could use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx rowversion and update based on it's value.  What you're asking us to do is identify the unique key on the table.    You'd know that better than us... Whatever that unique key is should be what you use to update.  If you don't have one then rowversion is the only option I can think of.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your schema if you're identifying the "2nd" row by sequence of ID values. What if the rows are inserted in the wrong order or updates occur? This seems more like magic than logic to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte as
(
    Select Title, Title_Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)
    From products.features
    where productid = '172'
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Title = ??? --<-- Your new value
where Title_Row = 2
```